# How to add single row from one dataframe to another?

Tags: r

I have a 2 dataframes that both have the same amount of columns but different amount of rows. Df 1 has rows with IDs from time point 1 and Df 2 should have rows with the same IDs but from time point 2. Df 1 should only have data from time point 1 but has some data from time point 2, so I would like to transfer  single rows in Df1 that have time point 2 data to Df 2.

I've extracted the values using something like this ID## <- T1[148] but can't find a way to add the extracted values to a new row at the bottom of Df2.

Comment: `rbind` sticks rows on the bottom of a data frame. So `rbind(Df2, Df1[Df1$timepoint == 2, ]` will stick rows from Df1 that have timepoint 2 on the bottom of Df2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to this:

1. `base` (pointed out by @Gregor):

```r
 Df2 <- rbind(Df2, Df1[Df1$timepoint == 2, ]
```

2. Using `dplyr` (`tidyverse`):

```r
      Df2 %>%
          rbind(Df1 %>%
          filter(timepoint == 2)) %>% # Add all rows from Df1 fitting the condition
          {.} -> Df2 # To save the changed Df2
```

3. Using `dplyr` (`tidyverse`) and `bind_rows` (pointed out by  @MrGumble):

```r
      Df2 %>%
          bind_rows(Df1 %>%
          filter(timepoint == 2)) %>% # Add all rows from Df1 fitting the condition
          {.} -> Df2 # To save the changed Df2
```

Comment: If you're running with `dplyr`, why not use the slightly more powerful `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of `rbind`?

Comment: @MrGumble I actually did not think of it but a quick google tells me that ```rbind``` is faster and preferred when the columns are the same which they are in this case. But I am not experienced enough with ```bind_rows``` to make a good call here, so I'll add it as an option.